# how do I switch to a specific tag in my svn repository in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn

I have tagged a revision of my working project in my svn repository in eclipse. How can I go back and reload that particular tag into my workspace?

Comment: Are you using eclipse svn plugin? Which one?

Comment: subversive with svnkit 1.7.5v1

Answer (score 1):

It should be done different ways, if you're using Subversive for example, try right-clicking on the project, *Team --> Switch ...*, and select the required tag using the *Browse* button. Make sure you don't have any uncommitted local modifications.

Comment: yeah that's what I thought however I got the error

Switch operation failed.
svn: E195012: 'https://yyyyyy.xxxx.xxxxx.gr/svn/kx/tags/20121113b4%20changes%20in%2085' shares no common ancestry with 'D:\ppou\dev\workspaces\ws01\kx-libs'

Comment: Hm, that's a strange error (it states that the URL you specified is independent from your working copy). Isn't there an ignore ancestry button for this?

Comment: there is no such button, not in the version of subversive I use...to do a --ignore-ancestry switch operation...I think deliberately as per [link](http://svn.haxx.se/dev/archive-2011-04/0373.shtml)..I just did a fresh check out of the tag within a new workspace

Comment: Oh, so that's a new feature then :-)